# Exceção java.lang.NumberFormatException (arquivos)

Tags: java

Galera, pelo o que eu chequei este código está tudo correto, inclusive depois do `String[] linha = arquivo.split(",");` se dermos um `System.out.println(linha[0] + linha[1] + linha[2])` ele retorna certinho `TV LED 1290.99 1`(linha do arquivo original `TV LED, 1290.99, 1`), mostrando que na posição 0 = TV LED, posição 1 = 1290.99 e posição 2 = 1. Mas na hora de passar a `String` 1 da posição 2 para `int` ele dá essa exceção... Por quê ?

```
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Digite o caminho do arquivo .csv.txt:");
    String caminho = sc.nextLine();

    File file = new File(caminho);
    String acharDiretorio = file.getParent();
    boolean criaSubPasta = new File(acharDiretorio, "\\out").mkdir();
    String criaArquivo = acharDiretorio + "\\out\\summary.csv";

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(caminho))){

        String arquivo = br.readLine();

        while(arquivo != null) {
        String[] linha = arquivo.split(",");

        String nome = linha[0];
        double preco = Double.parseDouble(linha[1]);
        int quantidade = Integer.parseInt(linha[2]); //erro aqui, java.lang.NumberFormatException

        list.add(new Product(nome, preco, quantidade));
        arquivo = br.readLine();
        }
        try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(criaArquivo))){

            for(Product produto : list) {
                bw.write(produto.getNome()+", "+ produto.total());
                bw.newLine();
            }
            System.out.println(criaArquivo + ": SUCESSO");
        }


    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Poste o log da exceção, ele mostra o que foi encontrado na variável que não foi possível parsear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É porque tá vindo um espaço em branco junto com o 1 depois da vírgula, tente um

```
linha[2].trim();
```

antes de fazer o parse pra Integer.